# Create Close Event To Emit from Custom Overlay

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript

So I've got a rails app using backbone.js and coffeescript. I've created a backbone view called "Overlay" that looks like this:

```
class MyApp.Views.Overlay extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['overlay']

  contentDiv: ->
    $('.overlay-content')

  initialize: (options) ->
    @content = options.content
    @width = options.width

  render: ->
    @$el.append @template()
    @contentDiv().append @content                                                                                                                 

  events: ->
    'click': 'overlayClick'
    'click .close': 'removeOverlay'

  overlayClick: (event) ->
    target = $(event.target)
    unless target.hasClass('overlay-content') or target.parents('.overlay-content').length > 0
      @removeOverlay()

  removeOverlay: ->
    @$('.overlay').remove()
```

and my template (which is hamljs)

```
.overlay
  .overlay-content
    %a.close Close
```

and I call it like so

```
@overlay = new MyApp.Views.Overlay(el: 'body', content: 'some content)
@overlay.render()
```

This is real simple, essentially you pass it some arbitrary string or html to be rendered in the overlay and it adds a nice lil overlay to the body.

What I am trying to do is write some code in the view that handles the generation of this overlay like so:

```
@overlay.on('close', someFunction)
```

However, I haven't the faintest clue how to go about doing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I, for one, am not entirely clear what you are trying to do.  Could you expand on your last few sentences?

Comment: If you want to use jQuery's event delegation to handle a custom event like "close", you'll need to trigger the event using jQuery as well: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backbone to trigger events from the view

```
removeOverlay: ->
  @$('.overlay').remove()
  @trigger('close')
```